# Использование переменных js в других файлах

Tags: javascript, php

Есть скрипт nodejs, собранный вебпаком:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const util = require("ethereumjs-util");

const privateKey = "0x" + crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
const publicAddr = "0x" + util.privateToAddress(privateKey).toString("hex");
```

Как я могу получить доступ к переменным privateKey и publicAddr в другом php файле?

Comment: Я не очень знаком с webpack и nodejs но насколько я знаю то вебпак это сборщик для фронтенда а php и node это серверные части. И просто напрямую передать данные скорее всего не получится. Разве только что делать аякс запрос с фронта и передавать данные на бэкенд. Но я могу ошибатся

Answer (score 0):

Просто отправить запрос к php файлу. Например вот так:

```js
const request = require('request');
request.post({url:'file',
 form: {privatekey:privateKey, publicaddr:publicAddr}},
 function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* .. */ 
})
```

Comment: к примеру вот так, можно в теле отправить , а не как форму